# An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll While writing from textbox to sql server 2012

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

Trying my first WPF textbox to SQL express connection. I am receiving a `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll` While using sql 2012 express trying to write to a table called

> EVUSERS

on database

> Employee

The error comes at

> connection.Open();

Here is my code.

```
void saveData()
        {
            try
            {
                string firstName = FNameTextbox.Text;

                string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;  Database=Employee;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        command.CommandText = " INSERT INTO EVUSERS (FName) VALUES (@FName)";

                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", firstName);

                        connection.Open();
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }         
       }
```

Here is an image of the table I am trying to insert the data into from the taxtbox. Employee.dbo.EVUSERS

*EDIT*
Screenshot

I have no idea why there is an error at the open(); Would it be the connections string? or the command I am using? The table definetely exists.

[image]

Comment: need more details about exception

Comment: try my the code from my latest edit

Comment: I tried your edit, but I am still having the same error unfortunately.

Comment: can you remove "user Instance=True" bit and try again?

Comment: Thank you all for your assistance. My issue was that in Management studio I had to grant myself privileges under windows authentication. to grant to everything. That was why it was always having the conn.open() issue. I thought as I was the windows admin that the priveleges were automatic, but they weren't. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open.aspx) says

1. Cannot open a connection without specifying a data source or server. or
2. The connection is already open.

So check your connection string

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Employee;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command= connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = " INSERT INTO EVUSERS (FName) VALUES (@FName)";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", firstName);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have two backslashes in the data source in your connection string, but have started the string with @ so do not need to escape the backslash.